# Move sets of files with date encoded names

Tags: unix, ubuntu, mv

I have a set of files that have dates in them.

lets call them:

```
 a20120528_120001.log
 b20120528_120003.log
 (name)(year)(month)(day)_(hour)(minute)(second).log
```

It is easy enough to move these two files simultaneously by doing:

```
 mv *20120528_12* file/
```

But now I have a situation where I want to move several hours worth of files in the same day ie:

```
 a20120528_120001.log
 b20120528_120003.log
 a20120528_130001.log
 b20120528_130003.log
 a20120528_140001.log
 b20120528_140003.log
```

Now if i wanted to transfer all of them i could just do the day:

```
 mv *20120528* file/
```

but what can I do if I only want to move hours 12 and 13, but exclude 14.

Please note this will need to be generic enough that i can input the date, because this will extend to be used across multiple days where there are 24 logs per day and several (between 3-8) will be excluded from each day.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ranges:

```
mv *20120528_1[23]* file/
```

For excluding everything from 3-8, go with the slightly more complicated:

```
mv *20120528_{0[0-29],[12]*}*
```

- `[0-29]` breaks down to the range `0-2` and `9`.
- `{A,B}` expands to `A` or `B`.

Comment: How will this work though if the hour is less then 10, because then you have to pad with a 0?

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question because in Bash, *filename expansion* uses only `*`, `?`, and `[`.  So you can deal with hours 12 and 13 only with the following:

```
[ab]20??????_1[23]????.log
```

Note that this takes you up to the year 2099 only; adjust accordingly if that bothers you.

But if you need a general range of values, you will need multiple commands.  If you have hours 00 through 23 and you want to exclude 03 through 08, I think you will need the following:

```
[ab]20??????_0[0129]????.log
[ab]20??????_1?????.log
[ab]20??????_2[0123]????.log
```

Of course you can also write a script to generate the proper patterns, using something more complex than filename globbing.  Not sure if you need that much complexity, though.

Comment: Is this indicating that I will need to do it in multiple steps? not a problem, just wondering?

Comment: I _think_ so.  I really don't know any other way to do filename expansion.  There are other forms of expansion in bash, like brace expansion, but I don't _think_ they expand into existing filenames.

Answer (score 0):

you may use THIS BATCH FILE

for /R SOURCEPATH %%f in (*20120528_12*,*20120528_13*) do MOVE "%%f" DESTINATION PATH

Comment: while I'm not certain as to if this is correct I see this answer could be made better by formatting it properly